# Detect Visual Studio version from within MSBuild project

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

The [BuildingInsideVisualStudio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171468.aspx) property provides the ability to detect whether a project is building inside Visual Studio.

Is there any way to determine which version of Visual Studio is being used ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the VisualStudioVersion property.

Comment: Created a project in VS2008 with the following added after `<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />`:

    <Target Name="PrintVisualStudioInfo">
      <Message Text="VisualStudioVersion: '$(VisualStudioVersion)'" />
    </Target>
    <PropertyGroup>
      <CompileDependsOn>
        PrintVisualStudioInfo;
        $(CompileDependsOn)
      </CompileDependsOn>
    </PropertyGroup>

Turned VS2008 output up to Normal. Result:

    Target PrintVisualStudioInfo:
        VisualStudioVersion: ''

On VS2010 Result:
    PrintVisualStudioInfo:
       VisualStudioVersion: '10.0'

Answer (score 8):

Since comments aren't formatted, here's investigation showing fsimonazzi is correct.
On 2008, VisualStudioVersion is NOT set. On 2010 (and up presumably) it is.

Created a project in VS2008 with the following added after `<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />`:

```
<Target Name="PrintVisualStudioInfo">
  <Message Text="VisualStudioVersion: '$(VisualStudioVersion)'" />
</Target>
<PropertyGroup>
  <CompileDependsOn>
    PrintVisualStudioInfo;
    $(CompileDependsOn)
  </CompileDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Turned VS2008 output up to Normal. Result:

```
Target PrintVisualStudioInfo:
    VisualStudioVersion: ''
```

On VS2010 Result:

```
PrintVisualStudioInfo:
   VisualStudioVersion: '10.0'
```

Comment: You can also run this on the command line with `msbuild.exe MyProject.csproj /t:PrintVisualStudioInfo` (supply the correct location of msbuild.exe and your csproj).

Answer (score 5):

According to [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/22/visual-studio-project-compatability-and-visualstudioversion.aspx) the property exists starting with the VS2012. It is defined in the `Microsoft.Common.targets` file when .NET 4.5 is installed (checked that original .NET 4.0 doesn't have the property defined).

Comment: Unfortunately, [the link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/22/visual-studio-project-compatability-and-visualstudioversion.aspx) does not exist any more. Does [this post](http://sedodream.com/2012/08/19/VisualStudioProjectCompatabilityAndVisualStudioVersion.aspx) contain the material you wanted to point to?

Comment: It appears to be. Since all such articles did belong to Sayed. But this really doesn't matter regarding the OP - I've already quoted the summary from there - the property is available starting with VS2012/.NET4.5. And my answer should really be a comment to another answer.