# How to determine the version of visual studio being used to build from within an msbuild file?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I want to use the compiler options described here:

http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/09/11/debugging-optimized-codenew-in-visual-studio-2012/

We have a base props sheet which gets included into all projects and would be the ideal place to set this option.

However, it seems that the compiler option changed name with Visual Studio 2013 with Update 3. Some developers in my department have not yet upgraded to this version, so I would like to dynamically select the correct name for this compiler option depending upon which version of visual studio is being used to build.

How can I do that?

---

I've seen there is a VisualStudioVersion property as described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/22/visual-studio-project-compatability-and-visualstudioversion.aspx

and here: [Detect Visual Studio version from within MSBuild project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11935426/detect-visual-studio-version-from-within-msbuild-project)

However, it seems that the value of that property changes depending upon the version of visual studio that was last used to edit the solution file, and it does not give the version of visual studio currently being used to build. (At least, that's how I read it, please correct me if that's wrong).

Hmm, also, I think it only gives the major visual studio version. I need to know which update version is being used too.

Comment: I think what you actually want is the version of the toolset, not of VS. Firstly MSbuild files can be built without using VS at all. Secondly when using VS you can select different toolset versions. Suppose you use VS2013 and set it to use the VS2012XP toolset your script really has no use knowing you are using VS2013. I'm pretty sure what you want is `PlatformToolset` and that is normally always defined before including any property sheets so you can safely use it in your base propsheet (just add sanity check to make sure it's not empty).